# Windows Service AggregateException at Production Server

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

We developed a windows service and use it at development time, 
the installation and working is normal on development time, 
when install the service at the production side, then the service 
start throwing the Aggregate function

The following is the log error of the thrown exception , that is thrown only at production server of client

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AutoLeaders.Infrastructure.ParseHelper.<GetInstallations>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at AutoLeaders.PushNotifications.PushNotificationsSender.notificationTimer_Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AutoLeaders.Infrastructure.ParseHelper.<GetInstallations>d__2.MoveNext()<---


System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AutoLeaders.Infrastructure.ParseHelper.<GetInstallations>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at AutoLeaders.PushNotifications.PushNotificationsSender.notificationTimer_Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AutoLeaders.Infrastructure.ParseHelper.<GetInstallations>d__2.MoveNext()<---
```

The following is code sample

```cs
namespace AutoLeaders.PushNotifications
{
    public partial class PushNotificationsSender : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer _notificationTimer;
        // Keep track of the last processed id.
        int _lastProcessedId;

        public PushNotificationsSender()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AutoLog = false;

            eventLogComponent = new EventLog();
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists("AL Push Notifications"))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("AL Push Notifications", "AL add-on Services");
            }
            eventLogComponent.Source = "AL Push Notifications";
            eventLogComponent.Log = "AL add-on Services";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _notificationTimer = new Timer();
            _notificationTimer.Elapsed += notificationTimer_Elapsed;
            _notificationTimer.Interval = 25 * 1000;
            _notificationTimer.Start();
            LogData.LogDataFile(string.Format("AL Push Notifications Service started at {0}.", DateTime.Now));
            eventLogComponent.WriteEntry(string.Format("AL Push Notifications Service started at {0}.", DateTime.Now), EventLogEntryType.Information, LogCodes.ServiceStarted);
        }

        public void OnDebug() 
        {
            _notificationTimer = new Timer();
            _notificationTimer.Elapsed += notificationTimer_Elapsed;
            _notificationTimer.Interval = 25 * 1000;
            _notificationTimer.Start();

            LogData.LogDataFile(string.Format("AL Push Notifications Service started at {0}.", DateTime.Now));
            eventLogComponent.WriteEntry(string.Format("AL Push Notifications Service started at {0}.", DateTime.Now), EventLogEntryType.Information, LogCodes.ServiceStarted);
            notificationTimer_Elapsed(null, null);
        }

        void notificationTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _notificationTimer.Enabled = false;

            try
            {
        // Code to handle timer 

                while (true)
                {
                    // Get installations from web service  
                   // Async function to call push notifications for mobile 

                }//while true
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try
                {// it seems exception cached here 
                    File.AppendAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Log.txt", ex.ToString() + "\n\n");
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }


            _notificationTimer.Enabled = true;

        }// notificationTimer
    }
}
```

Update

The production server is Windows Server 2012 , The visual studio to create the setup is visual Studio 2019

and here is more about the code

```
  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        _notificationTimer = new Timer();
        _notificationTimer.Elapsed += notificationTimer_Elapsed;
        _notificationTimer.Interval = 25 * 1000;
        _notificationTimer.Start();
        LogData.LogDataFile(string.Format("AL Push Notifications Service started at {0}.", DateTime.Now));
        eventLogComponent.WriteEntry(string.Format("AL Push Notifications Service started at {0}.", DateTime.Now), EventLogEntryType.Information, LogCodes.ServiceStarted);
    }
    void notificationTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        _notificationTimer.Enabled = false;


        try
        {
            LogData.LogDataFile(string.Format("Job started (notificationTimer_Elapsed(sender,e)) at {0}.", DateTime.Now));
            // Get Installation Objects
            var skip = 0;
            var pageIndex = 1;
            var limit = 100;
            while (true)
            {
                Get Data //
                foreach (......)
                {
                    if (true)
                    {
                        foreach (......)
                        {
                            using (DataBaseContext)
                            {
                                if (lastTrackRecord.RecordDate > currentDate)
                                {
                                    if (true)
                                    {
                                        if (true)
                                        {

                                            // Push Notofication HERE 
                                        }
                                    }
                                }//if currentDate
                            }// end using

                        } // end if foreach

                    }// if engine
                    #endregion



                } // foreach installation

            }//while true
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log Data                  
        }
        _notificationTimer.Enabled = true;
    }// notificationTimer
}
```

Comment: You error is caused by exceptions thrown in tasks that you didn't await.  You need to show more of your code.

Comment: @Nick I updated my post I added more code

Comment: `// Push Notofication HERE` is there a chance you are calling an Async method there?  Like, one that returns a Task?

Comment: public static async Task SendPushMessage(string deviceToken, string message) signature of the method @Nick

Answer (score 0):

So, according to your comments, you call the following method in `notificationTimer_Elapsed`:

```
public static async Task SendPushMessage(string deviceToken, string message)
```

This is an [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) method.  When you call it without using `await`, you basically fire-and-forget the call, and you cannot catch its exceptions anymore.  These exceptions will propagate in the form you see.

To resolve your issue, mark notificationTimer_Elapsed as `async`:

```
async void notificationTimer_Elapsed(...)
```

and use `await` to call `SendPushMessage`.

Comment: thank you for your help I will try it , but why this happened in production environment despite I installed the service at my device and this issue did not appear ?? @Nick

Comment: Because obviously on production SendPushMessage throws an exception, and it doesn't on your device.  If you amend the code as recommended, you will be able to properly catch and log the exception, and dig into the details of the reason.  Since Tasks throw an `AggregateException`, be sure to log also the `InnerException`.